# Java palindrome checker using queue AND restoring queue to original state

Tags: java, stack, queue, palindrome

I've written a long and complicated method checking if a list of elements in a Queue is a palindrome. I know it can be improved, but my goal right now is to get it to past all the tests in practice-it. I've passed 9 out of 10, but the only test I can't seem to pass is the odd elements/not a palindrome.

For example:
front [5, 10, -1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, -1, 10, 5] back. Expected Output should be FALSE. My Output is TRUE.

Also, unlike the other tests, the elements in the Queue aren't being displayed. Unlike the previous questions asked that are similar to this problem, my Queue must be **restored to its original state**. Here is my code so far:

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(Queue<Integer> q) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        int size = q.size();
        int extra = 0;

        if(q.isEmpty()) 
            return true;
        else 
            if (size % 2 == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
                    s.push(q.remove());
                }      
            while (!s.isEmpty()) {  // While Stack is not empty:
                if (s.peek() != q.peek()) {
                    int first = s.pop();
                    s.push(q.remove());
                    s.push(first);

                    while (!q.isEmpty())
                        s.push(q.remove());

                    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                        q.add(s.pop());
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            else {
                while (!q.isEmpty())
                    s.push(q.remove());

                while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                    q.add(s.pop());  // Restore Queue to original order
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < size / 2; k++) {
            q.add(q.remove());
            s.push(q.remove());
        }

        for (int l = 0; l < size / 2; l++)
            s.push(q.remove());

        while (!s.isEmpty())
            q.add(s.pop());
    }
    return true;
}
```

If anyone has a hard time reading this or can suggest a way to make it less convoluted as well, I would appreciate that. Thank you, and sorry again for the bloated code.

Comment: That's a lot of complicated code to check palidromity

Comment: @Cruncher agreed. Why not just turn the elements into a string and use StringBuilder.reverse() and a good old .equals() comparison?

Comment: @MarkW There's more efficient and more general solutions than that. In this case it's not actually that simple since [21, 25, 21] if you make a string is "212521", and if you reverse you get "125212" which is very different from the original. But just have a list and continually comparing index `i` with index `length-i-1` should do the trick. Works for any data type that you can call equals on.

Comment: @Cruncher yeah I overlooked that so +1.

Comment: @MarkW It's not, but [21, 25, 21] is in the general sense. Even if palindromes are traditionally Strings. But then again, a String is really a char array, which is a byte array which could very well be [21, 25, 21].

Comment: @Cruncher Damn youz and your unassailable logic!

Comment: @Cruncher It is, and I plan to ask how to refine the code once I pass the tests on Practice-It. I've been hammering at this method for a few hours (which is longer than I usually take) and I'd like to see this heap actually run. One thing I added on the comment on the code, I can only use one Stack as auxiliary storage.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the simple algorithm which doesn't care if it destroys the Queue in the process, but copy the Queue as the first step?

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(Queue<Integer> q) {
    return isPalindromeDestructive(copyQueue(q));
}

private static boolean isPalindromeDestructive(Queue<Integer> q) {
    //Destructive algorithm that treats q as disposable.
}

private static Queue<Integer> copyQueue(Queue<Integer> q) {
    return new LinkedList<Integer>(q);
}
```

You can implement copyQueue however you want, but this works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add that we may only use one Stack as auxiliary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Cruncher I went your way to copy the Queue. I was over-complicating the code by worrying about odd size Queues. I'd vote up your answer because that really helped, but not enough frequent flyer miles.

All it really took was throwing out the clunker I first posted, which is sometimes the best thing.

Anyway, here it is. The for-loop loads up the stack, making the copy Cruncher mentioned. The while-loop simply peeks and then reloads the Queue while popping the stack. Much cleaner, and it took me a couple of minutes after asking the right questions.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(Queue<Integer> q) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    int size = q.size();
    boolean palindrome = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int value = q.peek();
        s.push(value);
        q.remove();
        q.add(value);
    }

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
         if (s.peek() != q.peek())
            palindrome = false;
         s.pop();
         q.add(q.remove());
    }
    return palindrome;
}
```